# JQuery UI Sliding Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to create an About page with social media icons using jQuery and jQuery UI.

I have three icons that I'm using (which have all been provided by the wonderful [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/)): Facebook, Linkedin, and Mail. I'm attempting to create an interface that will slide open (to the left) text stating what social network the icon represents.

What's happening is that the text moves to a separate line then closes, and that, I definitely do not want. For me, on a Mac in Google Chrome, the JSFiddle provided below, it does so without animation, for some odd reason.

Although I've used jQuery a lot in the past, I've never used jQuery UI before, and it's being a bit of a pain now.

Check out the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LxS2z/2/).

My Javascript right now:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $( "#1" ).toggle( "slide" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing :

```
$( "#1" ).toggle("slide");
```

to :

```
 $(document).click(function() {
      $( "#1" ).toggle("slow" );
    });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LxS2z/3/)

Comment: Is there a smoother way of doing this? Due to the fact that it is text, it opens up vertically and horizontally... is there a way I can open it up horizontally only?